# SQL Server two different versions on same server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I've installed SQL Server 2000 with instance (`ServerName\SQL2000`) and SQL Server 2008 R2 with default instance (`ServerName`) on the same machine. Both work fine, I attached database to both via SQL Server Management Studio & Enterprise Manager.

I've two programs, one in vb6.0 and another in C#.

When I make a connections with both instances in vb6.0, it works fine. But when I try to connect to the SQL Server 2000 instance `ServerName\SQL2000` from C#, I get an error. It only accesses SQL Server 2008 R2.

I tried different connection strings but failed

```
Server=ServerName\SQL2000;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

also

```
Data Source=ServerName\SQL2000;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

**Error:**

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL  Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)*

Comment: Connection string I used in vb6.0 is
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myUsername; Password=myPassword; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=ServerName\SQL2000

Comment: please post the relevant c# code.

Comment: `using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=ServerName\SQL2000;uid=myUserId;pwd=MyPass;database=myDatabase;"))
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = Conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "Update users set isLocked=0";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }`